# How to test for/mock JSON in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have the following `data.ts`. Assuming all the setup is done with jest and all ( I'll point you to any setup errors I get if any), how do I test for/mock `team.json` in a `data.spec.ts`? I'm new to unit testing and cant find helpful step by step resources with typescript.

```js
import { Student } from '../models';

const data: Student[] = require('../data/team.json');

/**
 * Returns an array of students
 *
 * @export
 * @returns {Student[]}
 */
export function getStudentData(): Student[] {
 return data;
}
```

My `data.spec.ts`

```js
const getStudentData = require('./data');

test('gets students...', () => {
 // how to execute it here?
 
});
```

Example `team.json` data

```js
[
  {
    "login": "jason",
    "id": 1482046,
    "site_admin": false
  },
  {
    "login": "michael",
    "id": 1819122,
    "site_admin": false
  },
  {
    "login": "arnold",
    "id": 2323810,
    "admin": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you export `getStudentData()` as a named export, you should import it as `import { getStudentData } from './data'`

Then you can just call it inside your test function.

By the way, if you want to test loading of the data, you probably want to put your require function within the `getStudentData()`:

```
export function getStudentData() {
  return require('../data/team.json')
}
```

Comment: How do I test it out in the test function?

Comment: call it and make sure the data is loaded?